# How to prevent conflict animation with device rotation in android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, screen-rotation

I have a two button objects in activity this object has some move animation with ObjectAnimator these animations work perfect but when the animation is run in background i want to rotate device some times portrait mode coordinate in ObjectAnimator run in landscape mode or reverse.

```
ObjectAnimator move_next_btn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(next_btn, "x", next_btn.getX(),
                        next_btn.getX() + next_btn.getWidth());
```

in above code, the button should go out of the screen but after this line run, if device rotates to landscape mode button goes on middle screen I think when this problem occurs portrait coordinate run in landscape mode.

I give more detail with the picture:

1. this is my picture viewer with two buttons on the side when the user doesn't touch screen buttons with animation goes out of the screen:

[image]

2. second image show one of the arrows is hide (perhaps) I think it's because when animation wants to run I am rotated screen and arrow remain in out of screen:

[image]

3. in the third image when animation run in portrait mode I rotate to landscape mode
   and arrow stay in the center of the screen, of course, this image takes in portrait mode if again rotate to landscape arrow go on center:

[image]

this happens to occur just when move animation (int above code) and screen rotation run at the same time not always.

complete code:

```
private void init() {
        index = getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0);
        current_index = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_index", 0);

        final View previous_btn_rl = findViewById(R.id.previous_btn_rl);
        findViewById(R.id.previous_btn_rl).findViewById(R.id.previous_btn)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                time_to_hide_button = 3;
                try {
                    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                    if (current_index > 0) {
                        current_index--;
                        String path = "img" + "/" + String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/gallery/" + String.valueOf(current_index + 1) + ".jpg";
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(path)));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        final View next_btn_rl = findViewById(R.id.next_btn_rl);
        findViewById(R.id.next_btn_rl).findViewById(R.id.next_btn)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                time_to_hide_button = 3;

                try {
                    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                    int fileCount = assetManager.list("img" + "/" + String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/gallery").length;
                    if (current_index < (fileCount - 1)) {
                        current_index++;
                        String path = "img" + "/" + String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/gallery/" + String.valueOf(current_index + 1) + ".jpg";
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(path)));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (previous_btn_rl.getX() == -previous_btn_rl.getWidth()) {

                    ObjectAnimator move_previous_btn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(previous_btn_rl, "x", -previous_btn_rl.getWidth(), 0);
                    ObjectAnimator move_next_btn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(next_btn_rl, "x",
                            next_btn_rl.getX(),
                            next_btn_rl.getX() -next_btn_rl.getWidth());

                    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                    set.setDuration(500);
                    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    set.playTogether(move_previous_btn, move_next_btn);
                    set.start();
                }

                time_to_hide_button = 3;
                return false;
            }
        });

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            String path = "img" + "/" + String.valueOf(index + 1) + "/gallery/" + String.valueOf(current_index + 1) + ".jpg";
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(path)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "init: ");
        }

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (time_to_hide_button <= 0 && previous_btn_rl.getX() == 0) {

                    ObjectAnimator move_previous_btn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(previous_btn_rl, "x", 0, -previous_btn_rl.getWidth());
                    ObjectAnimator move_back_btn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(next_btn_rl, "x",
                            next_btn_rl.getX(),
                            next_btn_rl.getX() + next_btn_rl.getWidth());


                    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                    set.setDuration(500);
                    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    set.playTogether(move_previous_btn, move_back_btn);
                    set.start();

                } else {
                    if (time_to_hide_button > 0) {
                        time_to_hide_button--;
                    }
                }

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

I've recorded my problem:
[my problem video on youtube](https://youtu.be/8FfbQq7OSXg)

Whats the best way to prevent this problem?

Comment: It is still very hard to understand

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I don't know how to explain problem but all of things this when animation start if i rotate screen, right button coordinate set wrong and button go to center of screen this happen occur rarely. I send all of code probably you whats problem.

Comment: Why don't you lock the orientation when the animation is running and then unlock when the animation finishes?

Comment: attach video with this issue.

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I lock orientation with ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED and open with ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR and when lock animation work perfect but my min API level 17 and not works in low level API other option like SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR or SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED not working

Comment: damn... Why don't you cancel the animation and restart it when the activity gets recreated?

Comment: Can you put android:screenOrientation="portrait" for the activity in manifest and check what is happening now?

Comment: @YuriiTsap I've record video https://youtu.be/8FfbQq7OSXg

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I've record video

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira sorry I've fixed (forget share public)

Answer (score 1):

for a temporarily screen lock you can easily use:

```
//for android tablets **<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />**
//works perfectly... **WATCH OUT**: look portrait to reverse-portrait on api level 13 :)

currentActivity.setRequestedOrientation(currentActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);

//to re-enable sensor, just do:

currentActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```